# Change Dovecot mail directory

Tags: dovecot, imap

I've set up a mail server with Dovecot over SSL. It is receiving emails and placing them in the directory:

```
/home/*user*/Maildir/new
```

I can view them in Vim.

However, when I connect to the email via IMAP or Telnet, it does not retrieve anything. Is there somewhere I need to change a directory? Or does anyone have any ideas as to where to look for clue or potential issues. The mail logs are empty.

**UPDATE**

I found in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
```

But /var/mail/*user* is empty; my mail is is /home/*user*/Maildir/new

Crossed wires somewhere.

Comment: It would depend on MTA (probably postfix/exim) settings. If MTA is not configured to use dovecot as LDA (Local Delivery Agent) - it won't work

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how your mail server is setup. I had to change the following file: */etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf*, change the variable to:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

Because my mail is being saved there. It appears there are three different ways to save mail, see: https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/core/#core_setting-mail_location

Read to docs, find where you mail is being saved and change the configuration in */etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf* accordingly.

If you cannot find your mail in any of these locations, you probably have another error.